# inequalities for monotonic functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f,\tilde{f},g,\tilde{g}\colon\mathbb{R}\to[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be positive, continuous and increasing functions, with $f\geq \tilde{f}$ and $g\geq\tilde{g}$. Does it hold that
$$\int_a^r f'(x)g'(x)dx \geq \int_a^r \tilde{f}'(x)\tilde{g}'(x)dx $$
for all $r\in(a,b]$? If so why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not hold: Take $[a,b]=[0,1]$, $f(x)=g(x) = x+10$, $\tilde f(x)=\tilde g(x) = 2x$. Then $f\ge \tilde f$, $g\ge \tilde g$, but $f'=g'=1 < \tilde f'=\tilde g'=2$.

Comment: sorry forgot the most important part that the functions coincide on the boundary. thanks anyway.